# Creating a linked list graph from an array of structures

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, linked-list

so I'm trying to generate a graph using linked lists from an array of structures. Each structure contains a graph edge i.e. 2 nodes and a weight. The graph is undirected so there is also an edge from node2 to node1. The contents of each structure were scanned in from a text file (if it helps I can upload that too).

```
//
struct Edge{
    char node_1[20];
    char node_2[20];
    int weight;
};

\\declaring the array of structures
struct Edges edge[49];
```

I need to implement a shortest path algorithm once this is completed but I've been stuck on this step for a while.

UPDATE; this is the text file I scanned in

```
Carlisle    Newcastle   92
Nottingham  Birmingham  77
Leeds       York        39
Glasgow     Edinburgh   74
Moffat      Carlisle    65
Doncaster   Hull        76
Northampton Birmingham  90
Leicester   Lincoln     82
Sheffield   Birmingham  122
Lincoln     Doncaster   63
Sheffield   Doncaster   29
Bristol     Reading     130
Hull        Nottingham  145
Blackpool   Leeds       116
Birmingham  Bristol     139
Manchester  Leeds       64
Carlisle    Blackpool   140
Leicester   Northampton -61
Newcastle   York        135
Glasgow     Moffat      -28
Leicester   Sheffield   100
Carlisle    Liverpool   -30
Birmingham  Manchester  129
Oxford      Bristol     116
Leeds       Hull        89
Edinburgh   Carlisle    154
Nottingham  Sheffield   61
Liverpool   Manchester  56
Carlisle    Glasgow     50
Sheffield   Lincoln     74
York        Doncaster   55
Newcastle   Edinburgh   177
Leeds       Sheffield   53
Northampton Oxford      68
Manchester  Carlisle    20
```

Comment: you could implement the graph with an adjacency matrix. otherwise you need a node struct

Comment: also there isn't a concrete question. is your problem to create a linked list or just a graph or the algorithm for the shortest path?

Comment: The main objective is to create an algorithm for the shortest path. I assumed i should use a linked list to link up all the edges to create a graph. An adjacency matrix would also work if you could show me how to implement it. thanks

Comment: could you show me how the text file looks like? it seems a little bit wrong to use this edge struct since if a node appears more than one time, you're storing it's name more than one time

Comment: Yes thats the issue Ive been having. Ive updated the post with text file

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Data structure for your nodes

For example a (single) linked list:

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[20];
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

## 2 Algorithm to find the shortest path

You should choose the algorithm before implementing the edges because some of these work quite efficient or not on some data structures.

Since you have got negative weights in your data, some well-knowns like Dijkstra are not possible. It's even possible that your program will get to no solution due to negative cycles.

As far as I know, [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) should work.

## Final

Now it's up to you. If you get stuck on one of the steps above, feel free to ask.